# angularJS why I can't get data after $http

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I can't get data after $http, but it can get data in html
I write $http in service
this is code

**service.js:**

```
  angular.module('todoApp.services', []).factory('TodoService', function($http) {
    return {
      get_default_data: function($scope, url, par) {
        this.send(url, par).success(function(data) {
          $scope.data = data;
        });
      }
    })
```

and I use it in there

```
  todoApp.controller('WeekCtrl', function($scope, $http, TodoService) {
    TodoService.get_default_data($scope, 'get_default_data', {
      'type': 'week'
    });
```

this is problem：

I `console.log($scope.data)` in there:

```
  get_default_data: function($scope, url, par) {
    this.send(url, par).success(function(data) {
      $scope.data = data;
      console.log($scope.data)
    });
  },
```

it can show normal, but I `console.log` in there

```
TodoService.get_default_data($scope, 'get_default_data', {
  'type': 'week'
});
console.log($scope.data)
```

It show me `undefined` in console!
why?
and how can I get `$scope.data` in there?

Comment: Side note: `services` should not manipulate `$scope`

Comment: Because there's no data when you log it from controller. I think reading about how asynchronous functions work would benefit you.

Answer (score 1):

`TodoService.get_default_data` is async, which means it won't wait for the HTTP request to complete before moving on to the next line.

So by the time you console.log the data on the scope, it's undefined since the HTTP request has not completed yet, and there hasn't been a response, so the `$scope.data = data;` line has not yet been run.

Taking into account what Satpal said in the comments, you could refactor your code to return the promise to the controller and assign the data to the scope there:

**Service:**

```
get_default_data: function($scope, url, par) {
      return this.send(url, par);
}
```

**Controller:**

```
TodoService.get_default_data($scope, 'get_default_data', {
      'type': 'week'
    }).success(function(data) {
         $scope.data = data;
      });
```